# Python returning none instead of an array

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I made some code to solve a sudoku puzzle recursively, however when i go to return the output of the puzzle it returns none instead of the output, however printing the result at the end shows the correct solution

```
def sudoku(puzzle):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if(puzzle[y][x] == 0):
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if possible(puzzle,x,y,n):
                        puzzle[y][x] = n
                        sudoku(puzzle)
                        puzzle[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(puzzle)
    return puzzle

def possible(puzzle,x,y,n):
    for i in range(9):
        if (puzzle[y][i] == n):
            return False

    for i in range(9):
        if (puzzle[i][x] == n):
            return False

    x0 = (x//3)*3
    y0 = (y//3)*3

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if(puzzle[y0 + j][x0 + i] == n):
                return False
    return True
```

When I run this code, the correct solution gets printed to the console but the returned output is none. I suspect that this is caused by the line return, but I don't know how to go back to the previous level of recursion without this.

Comment: What do you expect the bare return statement on the 9th line of `sudoku` to do? Do you perhaps mean to use `break`?

Comment: When I use that return, it pushes me up to the previous level of recursion, break would simply break out of the 2nd for loop, which would not work, the return is for the case where the code hits a "deadend" and can't continue so it goes to the previous recursion and tries again